# How should I further troubleshoot port 53 incoming network connections?

Tags: debian, dns-hosting, nftables

I have a Debian 10 Buster server connected to a fiber Internet connection. I'm attempting to run a DNS service on port 53 of the server. What tools or techniques should I use to determine why packets are not arriving at my DNS service on the server?

### System setup

- One network adapter, `eno1` connected to the fiber modem.
- One network adapter, `eno2` connected to the LAN.
- Public IP `162.246.120.21`.
- `nftables` as my packet routing subsystem.

### nftables rules

```
table ip filter {                                                                                                                     
        chain input {                                                                                                                 
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;                                                                     
                ct state { established, related } accept
                iif "lo" accept
                tcp dport { ssh, 52, domain, http, https } counter log accept
                udp dport { 52, domain } counter log accept        
                iif "eno2" tcp dport { ssh, domain, http, https, microsoft-ds } counter log accept                                   
                iif "eno2" udp dport { domain, bootps, bootpc } accept
                iif "eno2" ip protocol icmp accept
                counter drop                                      
        }                                                                                                                            
 
        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
                ct state { established, related, new } accept    
                iif "lo" accept                                                                                                      
        }                      
                                                
        chain forward {                                                                                                              
                type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
                iif "eno1" oif "eno2" ct state { established, related } accept
                iif "eno2" oif "eno1" accept
                iif "eno1" oif "eno2" counter drop
                iif "eno1" oif "eno2" counter drop
        }
        chain postrouting {                                                                                                           
                type filter hook postrouting priority 0; policy accept;                                                               
        }                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                      
        chain INPUT {                                                                                                                 
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;                                                                     
        }                                               
                               
        chain FORWARD {                                                      
                type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
        }                                                                                                                            
                                                                      
        chain OUTPUT {                            
                type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        }                                                                                                                            
}
table ip nat {                                                                                                                       
        chain postrouting {                                        
                type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;        
                oifname "eno1" masquerade   
        }                                         
}
```

### Tests

- If I run the DNS server on port 52 instead of 53 my tests from remote servers work fine. Testing with `dig @162.246.129.21 -p 52 dns.my.tld`. Response is fast and correct.
- If I run the DNS server on port 53 and test from a system on my LAN it works fine. Testing with `dig @162.246.129.21 dns.my.tld`.
- If I add `nft` tracing rules I don't see remote traffic in the trace for port 53, but I do for port 52.

```
chain trace_chain { # handle 39                                                                                                          
   type filter hook prerouting priority -301; policy accept;                                                            
   iif "eno1" tcp dport { 52, 53 } nftrace set 1 # handle 40                                                                    
}
```

## Other

My ISP *solemnly swears* they don't block any incoming traffic, including port 53.

What other tools or techniques should I try?

Comment: Based on what you are saying, it sounds like something is dropping the traffic before it reaches this machine.  Is it only 53/udp that is dropped, by the way?

Comment: As far as I can tell, only 53. I've tested both tcp and udp - results are the same as far as I can tell.

Comment: Check your firewall. Check your router's firewall. Don't believe your ISP until it's working. But don't try this on a residential class connection.

Comment: Why not try it on a residential class connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my local ISP to finally admit to blocking, and unblock port 53 by running traceroutes to port 53 (both TCP and UDP) from a remote shell and emailing them the results.  They stonewalled me for 48 hours prior to that, insisting "no block exists"

Comment: What I ended up doing was created a separate login with sudo privileges and audit logging enabled on the server and gave the login to one of their technicians. They ran essentially the same analysis I did, but this time were convinced that they were in fact blocking incoming UDP port 53. They just didn't realize they were doing it.